# Periodically opening a web page in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, userscripts

I want my browser (Google Chrome) to periodically open a web page in new tab. The period must be configurable at a wide range.

A browser extension or userscript is acceptable.

Please do not suggest automatic update checkers and page scanners. I just want it to open the page, I will check it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Open a new tab or periodically refresh a tab you have open?  The latter would be less problematic.  Here's a userscript for that:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name    Periodically refresh page(s)
// @match   http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// ==/UserScript==

var days    = 0;
var hours   = 1;
var minutes = 44;
var seconds = 17;

setTimeout ( function () {
        location.reload ();
    },
    ( ( (days * 24 + hours) * 60 + minutes) * 60 + seconds) * 1000
);
```

---

If you really want to open new tab(s), that would be:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name    Periodically open new tabs or windows
// @match   http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// ==/UserScript==

var days    = 0;
var hours   = 1;
var minutes = 44;
var seconds = 17;
var url     = "Some URL";

//--- WARNING: will not work without changing Chrome settings and extensions.
setTimeout ( function () {
        window.open (url, '_blank');
    },
    ( ( (days * 24 + hours) * 60 + minutes) * 60 + seconds) * 1000
);
```

## BUT,

**You will also need to set the browser's pop-up blocker settings to allow it.**

You will also probably have to install an extension like [***One Window***](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/one-window/papnlnnbddhckngcblfljaelgceffobn).

Comment: There are always 5+ tabs are open in my browser. I want to reload a specific tab which is almost always in the background. I think the script you gave will only reload the foreground tab.

Comment: It reloads the tab based on the `@match` directive(s).  It should not matter if it's foreground or background.

Answer (score 1):

I have a low tech solution.
**Create the shortcut for the website in a windows folder**.
Use schedule app to open the shortcut periodically.
(I use [System scheduler](https://system-scheduler.en.softonic.com/) - easier than windows default one)